# Pricing near to expiration bonds using QuantLib

Tags: fixed-income, quantlib, zero-coupon

I want to get the theoretical price of a zero coupon bond each day using quantlib, I'm able do to this up to just before the maturity date where I get the following error: `# RuntimeError: non tradable at April 17th, 2023 settlement date (maturity being April 14th, 2023)`  I'm not sure if this is a bug with quantlib or a misunderstanding of how conventions work in fixed income so I came here to post the example below as I'm not sure why the settlement dates need to be tradeable.

```
import QuantLib as ql

settlement_days = 2
eval_date = ql.Date(13, 4, 2023)
rf_rate = 4.75845 / 100.0


def zero_coupon_bond(rf, dt, maturity, settlement_days=2):
    ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = dt
    zcb = ql.ZeroCouponBond(settlement_days, ql.UnitedStates(), 100, maturity)
    crv = ql.FlatForward(settlement_days, ql.UnitedStates(), rf, ql.Actual360()) 
    zcb_price = ql.BondFunctions.cleanPrice(zcb, crv)
    return zcb_price

# Example showing code working

maturity = ql.Date(19, 4, 2023)
print(zero_coupon_bond(rf_rate, eval_date, maturity, settlement_days))

# Near to maturity QL error

maturity = ql.Date(14, 4, 2023)
print(zero_coupon_bond(rf_rate, eval_date, maturity, settlement_days))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One day before maturity, the bond has still value for you (because you'll receive the final payment tomorrow) but it can no longer be traded, because the deal would settle after two settlement days, when the bond no longer exists.  Thus, you can call `bond.NPV()` which will give you the value of the final payment discounted by one day, but if you call `bond.cleanPrice()` you'll get that error.